# The behavior of the graph of $f(x) = \sin (\pi/x)$ as x approaches 0, Why?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

This is my first post.  I hope it is relevant.
for the $\lim_{x\to0}\sin(\pi/x)$ The limit does not exist.

I am curious if my logic is appropriate or if there is another way to understand this.

So what I believe is the following:

As $x\to 0$ we have that $  \pi/x\to\infty$

Therefore,  $\sin(\infty)$, which makes sense by the fact that as x approaches 0, the input of sine will increase to infinity or some large number.  As a result, sine will repeat its periods indefinitely.  It will oscillate between 1 and -1 indefinitely as x approaches 0.

I missed one thing and that is this is a two-sided limit, so sine's input is approaching positive and negative infinity

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}=t$ See what happens...

Comment: Looks like you basically have it, but note $\sin(\infty)$ isn't typically used in the way you do here. (Sometimes if a limit as $x \to \infty$ of $f(x)$ actually exists (as a real or maybe even an extended real), then $f(\infty)$ is used to denote that limit (+1 on question...)

Comment: @coffeemath If I use $1/x=t$ I fulfill your criteria because it would be $\lim{t\to\infty}sin(t)=sin(\infty)=f(\infty)$.  Oh but I can't do that because the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: Todd-- yes the limit doesn't exist, but on top of that the expression $\sin(\infty)$ is not defined (usually the domain of $\sin(x)$ is the set of (finite) real numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the idea: as $y$ goes to infinity $\sin y$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$ so every point between $[-1,1]$ is a limit point for $\sin y$. This shows that $\sin y$ does not have a limit in $\infty$. You could choose two sequences $(x_n)$ which go to $\infty$ and give different limits: for example $x_n = n\pi$ with $\sin x_n = 0$ and $x_n = 2n\pi+\pi/2$ with $\sin x_n = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

[image: graph of sin(π/x) with x axis changing from +/- 1 to +/- 0.01]

Graph of sin(π/x) with x axis changing from +/- 1 units to +/- 0.01 units. This shows graphically the intuition the OP had that the frequency of the sine wave approaches infinity.